# Trying To Create Dynamic Titles Via PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, page-title

I'm looking to create dynamic titles via user input. We are a financial website, and we have a quoting feature where users can enter a ticker and it displays the financial information about the company. The page runs fine, but I'm struggling with the titles for SEO purposes and to avoid duplicates.

I have created a PHP template called "quote", which is what is executed if a user enters a ticker query. This is the code I have to generate the title:

```
<title><?php if(isset($_GET['qm_symbol'])){
        $qm_symbol = $_GET['qm_symbol'];
    }
    if (is_page('quote') ) {
          echo $qm_symbol.'- Stock Quote & Stock News For '.$qm_symbol;
    }
?>
</title>
```

So, this works fine. It generates the titles as needed, and doesn't show anything on say a blog post where no input was placed. However, because I have the html outside of the PHP, it still generates a blank title tag and then below it the actual pages title tag generated by my theme.

For SEO purposes, I'd like to figure out how to code it so that if there is no user input, it doesn't output any title tags either. Any help on this? I imagine it is a simple solution, but I'm just struggling with getting the html integrated into the PHP. I imagine I cannot quote the echo statement, because it calls for the variable, being the ticker symbol.

Answer (score 1):

```
//At the top of your page
$pageTitle = (isset($_GET['qm_symbol'])) ? $_GET['qm_symbol'] . " - whatever here" : "default title";

//In your head tag
<title><?= $pageTitle ?> </title>
```

Do something like this.

Comment: In the event that the symbol isn't requested, won't this still place the empty title tags in the head of other pages?

Comment: No it would replace them with your default title which you should place where it says default title.

Comment: Yeah, essentially the problem I am running in to there is duplicate titles then. Because I would have the default title appearing from your code, and then Genesis's title. I've tried to figure out how to modify Genesis's title output to change it to my code, but I can't for the life of me figure it out, and their support is essentially non existent for stuff like that too.

Comment: You Must use `htmlentities()` on this or you Open yourself up to XSS Cross site scripting attacks.
All an attacker would need to do is put some JavaScript in a link to your site using this feature, and it would be injected into your page. `$pageTitle = (isset($_GET['qm_symbol'])) ? htmlentities($_GET['qm_symbol'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . " - whatever here" : "default title";` - Add that and then you'll get my blessing... :-)

Comment: Here is a post on Security stack exchange for this very thing: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/140433/xss-in-html-title-tag

Comment: @Dan I mean you can do it with javascript super easy: 
 <script>
 document.title = "This is the new page title.";
 </script>

Comment: I am not sure about the title tag in particular, as that is not actually part of the HTML body so it may be treated slightly differently, but as a rule of thumb you should always sanitize input data (especially $_GET) before using it. The problem happens when you take the URL parameters and evaluate them as HTML, because an attacker can do a phishing attack on your users by sending them an email that looks like some promotion or something from the site with a link (to the site) that contains JS in the query string, that you then inject into the page etc. And use that to steal session cookies

Comment: Its called a Reflected XSS attack.